# Passing table source as variable - Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I m trying to use source string from a variable and i m getting an error that i can not convert string to list.

I have the below step as source:

`= Table.Combine({#"File 2023", #"File 2024", #"File 2025"})`

I create a table and import this the below string as a value

`{#"File 2023", #"File 2024", #"File 2025"}`

Variable called `cnsList`created and the string succesfully passed into the variable.

When i use `= Table.Combine(cnsList)` i get the error that i can not use text as list.

Any ideas?

**Answer**

Create a blank query and paste:

`={#"File 2023", #"File 2024", #"File 2025"}`

This will generate a list. Rename the list to `FileList`. Use as follows:

`= Table.Combine(FileList)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Table.Combine(Expression.Evaluate(cnsList, #shared))
```

Comment: I get an error of Expression.Error: [1,2-1,32] The name File 2023' doesn't exist in the current context.
Details:
    [List]

Comment: in the transformation data step all looks ok but when i refresh the report i get an error of `We can not convert the value null to type Table`.

Comment: That looks like a different error. Paste your whole query (advanced editor) and screen shot of other tables into a new question so we can debug.

Comment: As soon as i replace the  new string with the old one i manage to refresh. I think is something rellated to the asnwer provided.

Comment: If the answer provided works in your Power Query editor, it should also work for the refresh too. Hard to debug without seeing more details

Comment: see edited question the error generated as soon as i press apply in the Transaformation data.

Comment: There isn't enough info to go on unfortunately. You need to supply more data including a screenshot of your other query names.